# Auto assign link-local IP address if DHCP not present?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ip, ip-address

In Ubuntu 22.04 network settings I have the option to manually choose to use a **link-local** address (which will be configured automatically if I do). I'm looking for the equivalent of the link-local option to be chosen automatically if there's no DHCP server detected on the network. This seems to happen on e.g. macOS and iOS when they're set to use DHCP as far as I can tell, and I find that very convenient.

One underlying problem that would be solved  by this is that when I connect my Raspberry Pi Zero with USB it's detected as a wired network interface, but it's given a new identity each time and therefore doesn't keep its network settings. I'd have to manually set it to link-local every time in order to access it.